# error: the platform is not currently connected

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, trigger.io

I am working with Trigger.io to build an iOS app from the terminal and on the last build step I get this output:

```
[   INFO] (lldb) connect
[   INFO] waiting for connection event
[   INFO] No connect event, assuming we are already connected
[   INFO] (lldb) run
[   INFO] error: the platform is not currently connected
```

Do you know what this error could mean? To be clear the device IS connected, and when I run Xcode it builds to the device, and when Trigger.io builds, the Trigger icon appears on the phone but it wont run, I just get the above error

Answer (score 0):

I had a build running from the Trigger.io application and when I tried to run from my terminal it caused a hang.

So make sure all other instances that could be running are quit.